# Ocaml - redefine a function inside a new function

Tags: ocaml

Sorry I'm not sure how to give a proper title for this problem:
If I do:

```
 let f1= function 1 -> failwith "a" | s ->s;;(*you can just use f1 x=x, just want to let f1 to have an exception case*)
 let f2 = 
     let f1= 
           try(print_string "s1";f1) 
           with _ -> (print_string "s2" ;failwith "s3") 
     in 
     let conv tm = f1 tm 
     in conv;;
 let f3 = 
     let conv tm = 
         let f1= 
             try(print_string "s1";f1) 
             with _ -> (print_string "s2" ;failwith "s3") 
         in 
         f1 tm 
     in conv;;
```

1. We can notice that "s1" is already printed while defining f2 (after loading this funcion), which means the new f1 is already excuted while loading f2
2. If we try f2 1 and f3 1, only f3 1 will print "s1".
3. Neither f2 nor f3 print "s2" when exception occurs

Now I'm a little confused about what's going on. f1 was actually redefined, even in f2, because if we do

```
let f4 = 
     let f1= ()
     in 
     let conv tm = f1 tm 
     in conv;;
```

An error for type checking will occur.

1. I don't know the difference between f2 and f3, because f1 is redefined before conv anyway.
2. Why in f3, even "s1" is printed, "s2" is not printed as I expected?

I'm using ocaml 4.01.0

Comment: I'd like to mention the difference between f2 and f3: in f2, f1 is a value, which is evaluated immediately after it's defined, so "s1" is printed after loading f2. In f3, conv is a function, so conv is not evaluated immediately, so    isn't f1. Therefore, "s1" is not printed in f3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is only thrown when `f1` is actually called. However, you don't call it inside the `try` block - in either `f2` or `f3` - you just evaluate the reference there and assign the return value to your local `f1` variable. The actual call which will cause the exception is always `f1 tm`.

You seem to be looking for

```
let f4 tm = try
              print_string "s1";
              f1 tm
            with
              _ -> print_string "s2";
                   failwith "s3";;
```

Comment: Cheers, this is my first question at stackoverflow and this is the first answer I received! Sorry I can't vote because I don't have enough reputation. I'm not sure if I should immediately accept this answer or waiting for a while. I also hope a comparison between f2 and f3 (f2 immediately output "s1" while loading) I think I've figured this out, so I'll accept this answer anyway. (Hopefully I can accept more answers, in case there're other good ones.